# Not able to print a variable inside a recursive loop function

Tags: functional-programming, erlang, elixir

I am trying to implement this very simple counter, where every time I calling my method it should increment and print it. But for some reason, it increments the counter but doesn't print it.

```
defmodule Node2 do

    def start() do
      initial = 0 
      loop(initial)
    end

    def loop(counter) do
      receive do 
        {:rumor, msg, from} ->

            IO.puts "#{msg} received from :"
            IO.inspect from
            counter = counter + 1
            IO.puts "Value of a Counter:"
            IO.puts counter

            loop(counter)

        {:get_counter, msg, from} ->
            IO.puts "Counter Value"
      end
    end

    def send_rumor(to_pid, from_pid, msg) do
      IO.puts "Send_rumor function!"
      send(to_pid, {:rumor, msg, from_pid})
    end
end
```

And my client method which calls it is defined as follows:

```
pid = spawn(fn -> Node2.start() end)
Node2.send_rumor(pid, self(), "Hello Sir!")
```

And the output is as follows:

```
Send_rumor function!
Hello Sir! received from :
#PID<0.77.0>
Value of a Counter:
```

It doesn't show the value of counter and prints blank.
But strangely when I make this little change to code, where I just print the variable initial in the start function, it gives me the output correctly.

```
def start() do
  initial = 0
  IO.puts initial
  loop(initial)
end
```

New Output :

```
Send_rumor function!
0
Hello Sir! received from :
#PID<0.77.0>
Value of a Counter:
1
```

I am new to Elixir, and so not really sure what is going on here?

Comment: Your code works for me. How are you running this program? Looks like a problem with your shell or IDE or wherever you're running this code.

Comment: @Dogbert I am just calling this function in my main program. My IDE is Sublime Text and I am running it on terminal.  Does it prints the value of the counter for you, even when you use my first start() function ?

Comment: Yes, with your first snippet of code loaded, I get `Value of a Counter:<newline>1` then 3 then 5 every time I execute `Node2.send_rumor(pid, self(), "Hello Sir!")`.

Comment: @Dogbert This is really weird. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @Dogbert it's weird that you get 1 then 3 then 5. I tried the code, and what I get is increment by one: 1,2,3, and so on. But @Shubh77, the counter number is shown too in my `iex`.

Comment: It can be reproduced here: http://elixirplayground.com?gist=72889b33ccafaf3b7c0a52c70baff764. This playground also reproduces case with `IO.puts` in `start` function.

Comment: @denis.peplin looks like https://stackoverflow.com/q/40311041/320615 / https://stackoverflow.com/q/39481242/320615 cc Shubh77

Comment: @Dogbert Ah, I see.

Comment: @denis.peplin That really helped. I would exit from the main process before the spawned process could print it out. Thank you.

Comment: You should also clarify how you use your client method too. Your code works for me. I call ` send_rumor ` function in `iex -S mix`.